# Bukkit NullPointer Plugin reference

Tags: java, bukkit

I am making a bukkit plugin that uses a config to store data, but when I use plugin.getConfig() I get a NullPointer. I think is it because of the reference to plugin, but how can I fix that?

The error is in the Storage class where I use the plugin. Instance

Main: http://pastebin.com/d3bFXbiR

```
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.LivingEntity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

   public void onEnable() {
      final FileConfiguration config = this.getConfig();

      config.options().copyDefaults(true);
      saveConfig();

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

      if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("BlockCmd")) {

         if (sender.isOp()) {
            if (args.length < 1) {
               sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "/BlockCmd [command] | Kijk naar het blok dat je wilt cmd'en");
            } else {
               Block block = ((LivingEntity) sender).getTargetBlock(null, 100);
               Location bl = block.getLocation();

               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
                  sb.append(args[i]).append(" ");
               }

               String allArgs = sb.toString().trim();

               Storage.addClickCmd(bl, allArgs);
               sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "[BlockCommand] " + ChatColor.BLUE + "Successfully added a command to the block");
               sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "[BlockCommand] " + ChatColor.BLUE + "Command: " + ChatColor.GREEN + allArgs);

            }

         } else {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Dit is alleen voor operators");
         }

      }
      return true;
   }

   @EventHandler
   public void onRightClick(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
      Player p = event.getPlayer();
      if ((event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) || (event.getAction() == Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
         Location loc = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
         int x = loc.getBlockX();
         int y = loc.getBlockY();
         int z = loc.getBlockZ();
         String w = p.getWorld().getName();

         String cCc = "Click.Cmd." + w + "." + x + "." + y + "." + z;

         if (Storage.getClickCmd(w, x, y, z) != null) {
            String cCc2 = Storage.getString(cCc);
            p.performCommand(cCc2);
         }

      }
   }
}
```

Storage: http://pastebin.com/wvQS3n57

```
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

public class Storage implements Listener {

   static Main plugin;

   public Storage(Main instance) {
      plugin = instance;
   }

   public static void addClickCmd(Location loc, String text) {
      int x = loc.getBlockX();
      int y = loc.getBlockY();
      int z = loc.getBlockZ();
      String w = loc.getWorld().getName();

      if (plugin != null && plugin.getConfig() != null) {
         System.out.println("Check");
      }
        //if(plugin.getConfig() !=null){}
      //plugin.getConfig().set("Click.Cmd." + w + "." + x + "." + y + "." + z, text);
   }

   public static String getClickCmd(String w, int x, int y, int z) {
      return plugin.getConfig().getString("Click.Cmd." + w + "." + x + "." + y + "." + z);
   }

   public static String getString(String path) {
      return plugin.getConfig().getString(path);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not saying that it definitely belongs there, but have you tried asking the [GameDev Stack Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)? It would also be wise to post at least some of that code here in your question 1) to prevent link rot 2) so that those of us who can't access pastebin due to firewall reasons can see it

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: The error is in storage: every thing whit plugin.

Comment: Could you post your full stacktrace please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `static Main plugin;` but it is never initialized, since you never instantiate a `Storage` object, only use its static functions.

In your plugin class create a `Storage` object, and initialize it in the `onEnable` method, passing the plugin for its constructor. For example:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

   Storage myStorage = null;

   public void onEnable() {
       final FileConfiguration config = this.getConfig();

       config.options().copyDefaults(true);
       saveConfig();
       myStorage = new Storage(this);
   }
```

Later in your plugin class use this object instead - and best to make your static methods in `Storage` (as well as the `plugin` member) non-static, since you will always need to create an instance to use the `plugin` set in the constructor.

I think [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) article gives a nice, basic overview about class members.